# Python: Simple Loop program

Tags: python, loops

So I want to make a simple loop program but I have a problem:

```
def Lottery():
    Cash = 200
    YourNumber = randint(1, 10)
    while YourNumber != WinningNumber:
        Cash = Cash - 10
        if Cash < 0:
            print("You are out of money!")
            break
        YourNumber = randint(1, 10)
    else:
        Cash = Cash + 100
        Lottery()
```

The problem is that in the last line of the def the "cash" will automatically reset to 200 again when restarting the loop. Maybe there is a really simple solution for this, but I've googled and tried without any results.

Comment: Please edit your code to fix the indentation.  It's not clear what code is supposed to be where.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing (infinite loop but breaks if you run out of money, without the recursive calling),

```
def Lottery():
    Cash = 200
    YourNumber = randint(1,10)
    while 1:
        if YourNumber != WinningNumber:
            Cash = Cash - 10
            if Cash <= 0:
                print("You are out of money!")
                break

            YourNumber = randint(1,10)
        else:
            Cash = Cash + 100
```

Comment: The `cash < 0` should probably be `cash <= 0`, as you would be out of money there, too, right?

Comment: Well the problem is that I wanted to have 200 to start off with, so you had some more chances to win. I don't know how to both get the 200 to start off with and then not reset it every time you win.

Comment: @EddieTallberg - I think my listing solves both of these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `Cash` as an argument, setting a default value:

```
def Lottery(Cash = 200):
    YourNumber = randint(1,10)
    while YourNumber != WinningNumber:
        Cash = Cash - 10
        if Cash < 0:
            print("You are out of money!")
            break

        YourNumber = randint(1,10)
    else:
        Cash = Cash + 100
        Lottery(Cash)
```

Code tip: you can use `+=` and `-=` as shortcuts for addition/subtraction and assignment, plus a couple other changes:

```
def lottery(cash = 200):
    while randint(1, 10) != WinningNumber:
        cash -= 10

        if cash <= 0:
            print("You are out of money!")
            break
    else:
        lottery(cash + 100)
```

Comment: This will make `Lottery` recursively call itself and never end.. I have a feeling the OP made a mistake designing the program like this.

Comment: @mutzmatron: How so? It'll start out with `200` in `Cash`, then each time either decreasing or reaching the `else` part, where it restarts with more `Cash`. If `Cash` reaches zero, all of the functions will end. No infinite recursion.

Comment: Ahh right missed the `break` - so... finite recursion. Lottery calling itself is not a good idea...see my answer above.

Comment: @mutzmatron: It could be homework that requires the use of recursion. Having a program that just generates random numbers and always ends in "You are out of money!" is not really a good idea either.

Comment: You could be right - though I only saw _simple loop_ in the OPs post, so I went down the simpler, recursion free path. But again, you could have interpreted correctly, who knows.

Comment: Works exactly as I wanted it to. Thanks alot!

Comment: often recursion is more straightforward and human parse-able than an infinite (or even finite) loop imho(as long as you are pretty sure you wont hit the recursion limit)...